# Error when deploying JPA Entity - SQL Syntax Error code 1064

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, glassfish, persistence

I have the following entity

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */   
 package com.travelagency.travelagencybackend.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="SITEUSER")
public class SiteUser implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int id;
    @Column
private String siteuser_username;
@Column
private String siteuser_password;
@Column
private String siteuser_name;
@Column
private String siteuser_email;

//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Getter and Setters">
 public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSiteuser_username() {
    return siteuser_username;
}

public void setSiteuser_username(String siteuser_username) {
    this.siteuser_username = siteuser_username;
}

public String getSiteuser_password() {
    return siteuser_password;
}

public void setSiteuser_password(String siteuser_password) {
    this.siteuser_password = siteuser_password;
}

public String getSiteuser_name() {
    return siteuser_name;
}

public void setSiteuser_name(String siteuser_name) {
    this.siteuser_name = siteuser_name;
}

public String getSiteuser_email() {
    return siteuser_email;
}

public void setSiteuser_email(String siteuser_email) {
    this.siteuser_email = siteuser_email;
}


//</editor-fold>


public SiteUser(){

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (int) id;
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof SiteUser)) {
        return false;
    }
    SiteUser other = (SiteUser) object;
    if (this.id != other.id) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.travelagency.travelagencybackend.entities.SiteUser[ id="   +     id + " ]";
}

}
```

When I try to deploy it to Glassfish I get the following error. Please note that I have gone through a number of posts already but none I found were related.

Here's the error:

```
 INFO:   file:/Z:/Fontys/ProEP/code/TravelAgency/TravelAgencyBackend /target    /classes/_travelagencyPU logout successful
    INFO:   visiting unvisited references
    INFO:   visiting unvisited references
    INFO:   com.travelagency.travelagencybackend.entities.SiteUser     actually     got transformed
    INFO:   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services -  2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
     INFO:   file:/Z:/Fontys/ProEP/code/TravelAgency/TravelAgencyBackend  /target  /classes/_travelagencyPU login successful
    WARNING:   Local Exception Stack: 
    Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -    2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
    Internal Exception:  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error  in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: CREATE TABLE SITEUSER (ID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, SITEUSER_EMAIL VARCHAR(255), SITEUSER_NAME VARCHAR(255), SITEUSER_PASSWORD VARCHAR(255), SITEUSER_USERNAME VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (ID))
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE TABLE SITEUSER (ID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, SITEUSER_EMAIL VARCHAR(255), SITEUSER_NAME VARCHAR(255), SITEUSER_PASSWORD VARCHAR(255), SITEUSER_USERNAME VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (ID))")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.processExceptionForCommError(DatabaseAccessor.java:1611)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:898)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:962)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:631)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2002)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataModifyQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:3214)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1737)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.priviledgedExecuteNonSelectingCall(AbstractSession.java:5008)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.DatabaseObjectDefinition.createOnDatabase(DatabaseObjectDefinition.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.SchemaManager.createObject(SchemaManager.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.TableCreator.createTables(TableCreator.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.TableCreator.createTables(TableCreator.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.TableCreator.createTables(TableCreator.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.SchemaManager.createDefaultTables(SchemaManager.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.generateDefaultTables(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.writeDDLToDatabase(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:3999)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.writeMetadataDDLToDatabase(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:4054)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.writeDDL(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:3965)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.writeDDL(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:3838)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:358)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:199)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor327.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1031)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3376)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3308)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1837)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1961)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2537)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeSimpleNonQuery(StatementImpl.java:1463)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2011)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1940)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1925)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:890)
    ... 78 more

INFO:   Portable JNDI names for EJB NewSessionBean: [java:global/TravelAgencyBackend/NewSessionBean, java:global/TravelAgencyBackend/NewSessionBean!com.travelagency.travelagencybackend.restresources.NewSessionBean]
INFO:   Portable JNDI names for EJB UserService: [java:global/TravelAgencyBackend/UserService, java:global/TravelAgencyBackend/UserService!com.travelagency.travelagencybackend.entityservices.UserService]
INFO:   Portable JNDI names for EJB UserDAO: [java:global/TravelAgencyBackend/UserDAO!com.travelagency.travelagencybackend.dao.UserDAO, java:global/TravelAgencyBackend/UserDAO]
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
INFO:   TravelAgencyBackend was successfully deployed in 15,892 milliseconds.
```

So, even though it says "successfully deployed" at the end; it does not create my table. Please help.

Comment: check out https://www.dbvis.com/forum/thread.jspa?threadID=4868

Answer (score 1):

Are you using MySQL? If so, SEQUENCE is not supported. You should change your generation strategy. Perhaps, use IDENTITY.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Comment: Hi Ish, I changed the generation type but still no change.